# Filter one column with multiple value

Tags: 2010, filter

Is it possible to filter one column with multiple values? 
It works in the Datasheet View but it doesen't work in the standard view. To add a new view with filtered values isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add link to your view with `?filter=1` parameter. On this page you will see filter that shows check boxes for each column. (I cannot test it for sp2010, but it works for sp2013).

Comment: Thanks for your advice but it doesn't help me. I tested it with the link. There are no check boxes in Sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Kwizcom Filters. It's 3th party wsp which could be use for this requirement